# Linq only ordering by first digit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I seem to be having trouble sorting as its only sorting the first digit

```
int storageCapacity;

IEnumerable<ProductStorageCapacity> items;

if (int.TryParse(filter["StorageCapacity"], out storageCapacity) && storageCapacity > 0)
     items = await context.ProductStorageCapacities
     .Where(ps => ps.StorageCapacity == storageCapacity)
     .OrderByDescending(ps => ps.StorageCapacity).ToListAsync();
else items = await context.ProductStorageCapacities
     .OrderBy(ps => ps.StorageCapacity).ToListAsync();
```

Any help?

Comment: You are selecting only items with a specific `StorageCapacity`, then you are ordering by that value. That's pointless because all items will have the same value so you'll get an arbitrary ordering.

Comment: As per @Tim comment, I assume you are asking about `else` case. What is `StorageCapacity`'s type? Also, what is the point of using `ToListAsync` and immediately `await` the result?

Comment: public int StorageCapacity { get; set; } - it's an int

Comment: @slawekwin - I suspect because thats what the docs tell you to do: `Multiple active operations on the same context instance are not supported. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context.`

Comment: @momo003 - in which case this question doesnt make sense - there's no such thing as the "first digit" of an int. An int is an int is an int. If you order by it, you get a numerical ordering.

Comment: @Jamiec here's an example: 0, 500, 1000 (ascending is fine) but when I order it descending it'll return 0, 1000, 500

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere down the line, your `StorageCapacity` is  a string.

Look at this code (Live example: http://rextester.com/NZALE31796):

```
var intList = new []{0,500,1000};
var strList = new []{ "0", "500", "1000"};


Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",intList.OrderByDescending(x => x)));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",strList.OrderByDescending(x => x)));
```

The output is:

> 1000,500,0
>   500,1000,0

The first result is what you would expect ordering ints descending. The second is what you get from the same input of strings.